# How to create record type of two tables in PL/SQL?

Tags: plsql

I have two tables A,B with lots of columns and a cursor

```
CURSOR Cur  
IS 
select A.*, B.* FROM A,B
```

I want to fetch the cursor into a TYPE that stored the rowtype of two tables.
However, I do not want to create a TYPE by typing all of the column name of two tables.  I tried the following but neither of them work.

```
--1

RecA                 A%RowType
RecB                 B%RowType
FETCH Cur INTO RecA, RecB

--2

RecA                 A%RowType
RecB                 B%RowType
RecAB                A||B%RowType
FETCH Cur INTO RecAB
```

P.S. The problem can be solved by using two cursors but I want to know is there a way to concat two rowtype.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reading [the fine manual](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/rowtype_attribute.htm):

[image]

> ***explicit_cursor_name***
>
> Name of an explicit cursor. For every column selected by the query associated with *`explicit_cursor_name`*, the record has a field with the same name and data type.

So you can simple say:

`type cur_t is cur%rowtype;`

Also see [the examples](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/composites.htm#CBJCGDHB).